# Behavior change in SimpleDateFormat in java 1.7?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Consider following snippet

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, java.text.ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        f.setLenient(false);
        String dateStr = "2008-01-23 00:00:00.0";
        Date date=f.parse(dateStr);
        System.out.println(date);

    }
}
```

this works fine in java 1.6 and gives output **Wed Jan 23 00:00:00 IST 2008**

In case of java 1.7 it gives Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2008-01-23 00:00:00.0"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

I think JAVA 1.7 behavior is correct because **00:00:00.0** doesn't come under **hh:mm:ss** format (1-12 hr format)

Is my assumption is correct that 1.6 has bug and is corrected in 1.7?

Comment: Your assumption is right, just couldn't find bug offhand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this behaviour has changed with Java 7. The bugfix documentation can be found on [Oracle website](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4396385). The bug-id is JDK-4396385.